# How to update all tables in specific schema in dev database from prod database in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, database-migration, standards

I am trying to use Export data option to copy data from source to destination table wise, but it throws an error if there is any foreign key relationship, this error is because, if I selected a parent table and tried to push data to destination without selecting child table, it will throw an error because the new id information which is in parent table is not present in the child table of destination database.

How can I copy all the tables in specific schema with data to destination database schema by handling foreign key relationship?(The schema names and schema of tables are same in both the databases)

I am using SSMS, is there any script that can do this job using script as I have more than 1000 tables in database, it will be hard to manually select all tables and copy them?

So I am in interested in the second option! Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

[image]

**Foreign key Error message:**

> Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
> An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record
> is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server"
> Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been
> terminated.". An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE
> DB Driver for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The
> INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> "FK_Table1_Table2". The conflict occurred in database
> "DevDB", table "schema_1.Table2", column
> 'column_name'.".  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: [Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372166/we-are-not-a-code-writing-service-comments-are-they-the-good-the-bad-or-the-u)

Comment: @Luuk Can you suggest an approach atleast? I assume stackoverflow is free helping each other tech community :)

Comment: Check out visual studio sql server data tools, it has some sort of data compare tool, where you can fill out the data from source to destination. The community edition is free

Comment: You could temporarily disable foreign keys also. Or maybe it's an option in the ssms export wizard already

Answer (score 0):

You could disable all foreign keys and disable them when you're done migrating the data

```
SELECT  'ALTER TABLE ['+[TABLES].[name]+'] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ['+[KEYS].[name]+']',
 'ALTER TABLE ['+[TABLES].[name]+'] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ['+[KEYS].[name]+']'
FROM sys.foreign_keys as [KEYS]
JOIN sys.tables AS [TABLES] 
    ON [KEYS].parent_object_id = [TABLES].object_id
```

The query will generate all statements. The disabling will be done in a second, the en-abling depend on how-ever large the dataset is that needs to be checked.

In general you don't want to move large amounts of data to a new table with constraint enabled. Wether they are FK constraint, PK constraints or any other type. It's much faster to enable/rebuild those later then to load data with all constraints dragging down the proces.